# Character rotation depending on camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I've spent my whole day trying to figure out a problem I'm having with my school project, so I'm off to my last resort: stackoverflow!

**My problem:**
I'm trying to rotate a character relative to a Camera you can rotate around the character.

**input:** xbox controller

**relevant information:**

- The camera rotates horizontally around the character, using the right joystick
- The character movement happens with the left joystick
- The character already moves relative to the Camera, that's working as expected. **I'm trying to rotate the character**, which happens in a seperate method.
- When the left joystick is pulled downwards, the character should always be facing (and moving towards) the camera.
- When the left joystick is pulled upwards, the character should always be facing the opposite of (and moving away from) the camera.
- I'm leaving a lot of code out, just to keep it readable for you guys. If you need something, just ask and I'll provide.

  [image: inspector:]
  **What I have so far:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vvgG.jpg

**Why it's wrong:** The character rotation is perfect. However, I'm cheating here. The camera rotates according to the world coordinates. As soon as I rotate the camera, this is obvious.

The following script is attached to the Character GameObject.

```
public class CharacterBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject HumanoidModel;
    [SerializeField]private Transform _mainCameraTransform;

    private void Update()
    {
        ApplyMovement();
        RotateCharacter();
    }

    private void ApplyMovement()
    {
        //get input movement vector
        Vector3 inputMovement = new Vector3(_inputMoveCharacterXAxis, 0, _inputMoveCharacterZAxis);

        //make sure camera forward is player movement forward
        Vector3 mainCameraForwardXz = Vector3.Scale(_mainCameraTransform.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)); //multiplied by (1, 0, 1) to remove Y component
        Vector3 mainCameraRightXz = Vector3.Scale(_mainCameraTransform.right, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)); //multiplied by (1, 0, 1) to remove Y component

        Vector3 movementInCameraForwardDirection = mainCameraForwardXz * inputMovement.z;
        Vector3 movementInCameraRightDirection = mainCameraRightXz * inputMovement.x;

        Vector3 movementForward = movementInCameraForwardDirection + movementInCameraRightDirection;

        _velocity = movementForward * MaximumSpeed;
    }

    private void RotateCharacter()
    {
        Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(_inputMoveCharacterXAxis, 0, _inputMoveCharacterZAxis);
        HumanoidModel.transform.LookAt(HumanoidModel.transform.position + 
        HumanoidModel.transform.forward + inputDirection);
    }
```

The following script is attached to the Main Camera GameObject

```
public class CameraBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _characterTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _mainCameraTransform;

    private void Update ()
    {
        RotateCamera();
    }

    // Rotate camera horizontally
    private void RotateCamera()
    {
        _mainCameraTransform.RotateAround(_characterTransform.position, Vector3.up, _inputRotateCameraHorizontal);
    }
}
```

**The source of the problem is in the RotateCharacter() function. I know I need to get some calculations in there to make the character rotation relative to the camera rotation, I just can't figure out what that calculation is, and why.**

Thanks in advance!

Thrindil

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html ?

Comment: @Aybe I've already tried transform.rotate, but haven't been succesful so far.
In a perfect world, I would use the Transform.Rotate((float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle, Space relativeTo) method, in which I would say Space relativeTo = Camera.Transform.Forward, or something like that.
Because I want my character rotation to be dependent of it.

Comment: Isn't what you're looking for a 3rd person camera ? Check this : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/unity3d-third-person-cameras--mobile-11230

Answer (score 0):

so heres what you need...

camDefault, a Vector3 for the cameras initial position behind the char.
camCur,  a Vector3 for the cameras current position(to track where it is in `orbit` around the character)

you need to  set camDefault in Awake() to the its current position at that time, IE `camDefault = cam.transform.position);`

then in a fixed update,

`camCur= cam.transform.position;`

then,

```
 if(Input//your horizontal axis here//==0){
if(camCur!=camDefault){
//translate camera to cam default
cam.tranform.translate(camDefault);

cam.lookat(player.transform.forward);

}
}
```

keep in mind that some of this is pseudocode, just a general direction. but the unity methods are there. if properly implemented this script will allow you to rotate around your char with right stick, than the camera will slide back behind you when you let go.

I believe, for your sanity, it would be easier to make the camera a direct child of ybot, so it rotates with it and you dont need to do it maually the camera will always stay behind the player. but thats just my opinion. as it sits now, the camera, and the model are children of player, if you want the camera to turn with the player, just make it a child of that model.

in this case, you could store the initial rotation, and current rotation as above, and us your stick to look left and right and then snap back to forward when you let the stick go.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understood my question.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks to me that you're showing me how to rotate the camera around the character. However, I've already succesfully implemented this. I'm having trouble with my character rotation.
What I want to do is this:
The right joystick rotates the camera (works)
The left joystick moves the character, depending on the camera rotation.
If I hold left joystick down, I want the character to walk towards the camera.
If I hold left joystick up, I want the character to walk away from the camera, etc.